# php ssh2_exec hangs on "crontab -e" command

Tags: centos, php, ssh, cron

I connected to remote server with `ssh2_connect`. In my secure log I got

```
Feb 22 11:41:57 centos sshd[3243]: Accepted publickey for subscr from 83.166.241.41 port 53306 ssh2
Feb 22 11:41:57 centos sshd[3243]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user subscr by (uid=0)
```

All shell commands working, but wen I try "crontab -e" my php script hangs

In `crontab` log I see

```
Feb 22 11:41:57 centos crontab[3248]: (subscr) BEGIN EDIT (subscr)
```

I tried "crontab -r" command and it works. In crontab log I see

```
Feb 22 11:41:37 centos crontab[3205]: (subscr) DELETE (subscr)
```

So I GUESS all permissions is fine.

My question is why php script hangs only when I run

```
ssh2_exec($conn, "crontab -e");
```

Answer (score 2):

`crontab -e` issues interactive editor to modify the `crontab` for the running user. If you are running in `php`, you most probably don't have local terminal and anything that would be able to show the editor for you (there is no way to show it in your browser either, unless you have some special emulator there).

Comment: But this is working in other projects when I increase memory limits. For example it's OK on amazon aws >= small instance, but not for <= micro instance